# Me piden crear una función palíndromo

Tags: python, condiciones, while

Si utilizo return funciona bien

```
def palindromo(palabra):

    primera= 0
    ultima = len(palabra) - 1
    while palabra [primera] == palabra [ultima]: 
        if primera >ultima: 
            return 'Sí es palíndromo'
        primera+= 1 
        ultima -= 1 
    return 'No es palíndromo' 

print(palindromo('anilina'))
```

Pero si utilizo print me da error string index out of range y también me señala la línea en la que invoco la función

```
def palindromo(palabra):

    primera=0
    ultima=len(palabra)-1
    while palabra [primera]==palabra [ultima]:
        if primera>ultima:
            print ('Sí es palíndromo')
        primera+=1
        ultima-=1
    print('No es palíndromo')
palindromo('anilina')
```

Comment: pon `return` tras el `print`

Comment: Python es un lenguaje de muy alto nivel. Mira, versión en una línea de la función que te piden: `def palindromo(palabra): return palabra == palabra[::-1]`

Comment: Otra, si la anterior no te gusto: `def palindronomico(palabra):
    return all(palabra[i] == palabra[-i] for i in range(1 + len(palabra) // 2))`

Comment: Muchas gracias a los dos

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que en el segundo caso, sigues ejecutando el bucle while (y todo lo que tiene dentro)

De hecho, en tu ejemplo ya no es sólo que tengas un error, es que además imprimes tres veces la frase `Sí es palíndromo`, porque pasas tres veces por ahí.

Además, como nunca sales del while, `primera` y `última` siguen incrementando y decrementando sus valores y llega un momento en el que salen fuera de índice y al hacer esta comparación `palabra[primera]==palabra[ultima]` se da el problema.

Cuando imprimes la frase, tienes que poder modificar el *flujo de ejecución* de alguna manera.

En tu primer caso modificabas ese flujo con un `return`, ya que `return` lo que hace (además de devolver el valor especificado) es "terminar" cualquier código de la función. No vas a seguir ejecutando más código.

Así que si quieres que funcione tu función con prints deberías hacer algo similar: una vez imprimido, evitamos el resto del código (y bucle)

Hay muchas opciones:

- Puedes poner un return justo después del primer print. En este caso no es necesario devolver nada, pero simplemente lo usamos para poder terminar la función. Tampoco es necesario ponerlo después del segundo print, porque no hay nada más después
- Puedes utilizar un `break` después del primer print. `break` lo que hace es "abortar el bucle actual", de manera que el flujo de ejecución sigue por el segundo print. Obviamente no quieres hacer ese segundo print si realmente la palabra no es palíndroma así que deberás añadir alguna condición extra como en este ejemplo:

Ejemplo:

```
def palindromo(palabra):
    primera=0
    ultima=len(palabra)-1
    while palabra [primera]==palabra [ultima]:
        if primera>ultima:
            print ('Sí es palíndromo')
            break;
        primera+=1
        ultima-=1
    if primera < ultima:
        print('No es palíndromo')
```

- Finalmente puedes modificar la condición del while para que no siga ejecutándose una vez que "primera" sobrepasa "segunda". Y al final del código (ya fuera del bucle) imprimir en función del resultado de esas dos variables que se han modificado previamente:

Ejemplo:

```
def palindromo(palabra):
    primera=0
    ultima=len(palabra)-1
    while palabra [primera]==palabra [ultima] and primera < ultima:
        primera+=1
        ultima-=1
    if primera < ultima:
        print('No es palíndromo')
    else:
        print ('Sí es palíndromo')
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Julio

Comment: De nada @Neco, recuerda que puedes marcar la respuesta como "aceptada" si crees que responde a tu pregunta